# Substitution to reduce differential equation to Clairaut's form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Use the substitution $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ to reduce the differential equation $(p^2+1)(x-y)^2=(x+yp)^2$ to Clairaut's form.

I tried with the above substitution, however I failed. I could not visualize how do I proceed from here.

Comment: What do you get after you substitute it? Add it to the question so that you can help the people see what you are struggling with.

Comment: Please post the question in the text, not (only) in the title. Consider using https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (mathjax), which is a markup language used on this site. (Similar to tex / latex.) Show explicitly what you tried, else there will be many downvotes, this is frustrating for both, the one that post, the ones that read.

Comment: Duplicate of [Solve $\{(\frac{dy}{dx})^2+1\}(x-y)^2=(x+y\frac{dy}{dx})^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1560790/115115), without an answer to the problem as posed.

Answer (score 0):

For some unspecified parameter $t$ along the solution curve, you can set $p=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\dot y}{\dot x}$ and remove denominators to get
$$
(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)(x-y)^2=(x\,\dot x+y\,\dot y)^2
$$
Now insert 
$$
\dot x=\cosθ\,\dot r-r\sinθ\,\dot θ,\\
\dot y=\sinθ\,\dot r+r\cosθ\,\dot θ.\\
$$
leading to
$$
(\dot r^2+r^2\dotθ^2)(1-\sin(2θ))=\dot r^2
\implies
\frac{1-\sin(2θ)}{\sin(2θ)}\dotθ^2=\frac{\dot r^2}{r^2}.
$$
Can you see the Clairaut equation in there?